# How to make custom dialog more wider?

Tags: android, customdialog

My custom dialog is narrow.I want more little wider dialog.
So,I add some padding and it change a little..If this padding are annoying,just forget it.
Please give me some ideas for custom dialog more wider.
This is screenshot [ScreenShot](http://www.imagebam.com/image/806ce1311041687)

Here is my custom dialog layout xml
layout_customdialog.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnViewCur_close"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="@drawable/closebutton_selector"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ok"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/transparent" />

    </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleCustomWorldCurrencyText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/titleCurrencyCustom"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/Green"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:typeface="serif" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" >

        <!-- -add your views here -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/usdWorldCurCustomDialogText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/SkyBlue"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/lblUsdCustomDialog"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/usdWorldCurCustomEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/worldCurCustomDialogText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/SkyBlue"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/worldCurCustomDialogEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" >

            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCurrencyCustomConvert"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/btnCurrencyCustomConvert" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is java file

```
Dialog dialogCur = new Dialog(MainTabActivity.this);
Window windowCur = dialogCur.getWindow();

dialogCur.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialogCur.setContentView(R.layout.layout_customdialog);

    //acquire ids, I skip them

dialogCur.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); 

dialogCur.show();

btnCloseCustomDialogCurrency
                            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    dialogCur.dismiss();

                                }

                            });

                    btnConvertCurrency
                            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                                }

                            });
```

Comment: post your screen shot as It is not able to open here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line after **setContentView()**

```
   dialogCur.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly..thz..please wait 5 minutes to accept answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I am unable to see the screen shot but you might facing problem like mine.

Try this:

```
dialogCur.show();

dialogCur.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

Comment: **FILL_PARENT** is deprecated. Use match_parent.